# SQL Query with conditional JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

The scenario:

**Table1**
CatId|Name|Description

**Table2**
ItId|Title|Date|CatId (foreign key)

I want to return all rows from Table1 and Title,Date from Table2, where
The returned  from Table 2 must be the Latest one by the date column.
(in second table there many items with same CatId and I need just the latest)

I have 2 queries but can't merge them together:

```
Query 1:  
SELECT Table1.Name,  Table1.Description,
       Table2.Title, Table2.Date
FROM 
       Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CatId=Table2.CatId

Query2:

SELECT TOP 1 Table2.Title, Table2.Date
FROM 
    Table2
WHERE 
    Table2.CatId = @inputParam
ORDER BY Table2.Date DESC
```

Comment: Can you try to explain the question better? I think you are saying that you want to return every row from table1 and with each row, and Title and Data column from table2 for the latest (most recent Data) row in table2 whos CatID matchs the CatID in table1

Comment: @thecoshman , yes that's right.
All rows from Table1 and the Title and Data values should be from the latest record of table2 (with same catid)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're talking about a groupwise maximum (newest row in `Table2` for each matching row in `Table1`), in which case, the easiest way is use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        t1.Name, t1.Description, t2.Title, t2.Date,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.CatId ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) AS Seq
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
        ON t2.CatId = t1.CatId
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Seq = 1
OR Date IS NULL
```

Comment: in PARTITION BY t1.CatId ORDER BY t2.Date, I can also have t2.CatId ORDER BY t2.Date, right?

Comment: @mariki: Yes, that column just might be `NULL` since it's a `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: and last question, is there a reason you used WITH..AS?
Why not simply move SELECT * FROM to top?

Comment: @mariki: You can't filter on the `Seq` column (row number) unless it's inside either a CTE or derived table.

Comment: @Aaronaught, I mean I wrap all with SELECT * FROM (...)TT and then 
WHERE TT.Seq = 1
OR Date IS NULL

Comment: @mariki: Because CTEs are easier to read than subqueries?  You can do it using a subquery if you want, you'll get the same results.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You can use a `UNION`, but you'll need to make the columns match up:</strike>

OK, after rereading the question, I understand what you're trying to do.

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT Table1.Name,  Table1.Description,
 T2.Title, T2.Date

FROM
 Table1

LEFT JOIN (
 SELECT CatId, Title, Date, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY CatId, Date DESC) - RANK() over (ORDER BY CatID) as Num

 FROM  Table2) T2 on T2.CatId = Table1.CatId AND T2.Num = 0
```

Comment: why do you have - RANK() over..., why it's needed?

Comment: @mariki: This is what "groups" the dates by `CatId`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work?

```
SELECT Table1.Name,  Table1.Description,
   T2.Title, T2.Date
FROM 
   Table1 LEFT JOIN (

SELECT TOP 1 Table2.CatId Table2.Title, Table2.Date
FROM 
Table2
WHERE 
Table2.CatId = Table1.catId 
ORDER BY Table2.Date DESC

) T2 
ON Table1.CatId=T2.CatId
```

Comment: the inputparam is the returned catId from table1

Comment: I get an error on = Table1.CatId  The multi-part identifier "Table1.CatId" could not be bound.