# Combine SQL query with JOIN and conditionals

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a combination of querys, joins, and conditions. I have checked some similar questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630184/sql-query-with-conditional-join), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630184/sql-query-with-conditional-join)) but still is not working.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT colx, coly, colz
FROM T2
WHERE colz = 1) ON col1=coly
```

I'm trying to JOIN T1 with T2 with `col1=coly` where `colz=1`. Each table has 100 columns, I just need `col1, col2, col3`, and `colx, coly, colz`.

Besides, it this approach the most efficient?

Comment: provide sample data and desired result. we can't guess what you are trying to do.

Comment: Explain what "not working" means.  Why are you using a `left join` if you are not selecting any columns from the second table?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I just added a explanation. I didn't do it because I thought it was explicit. What do you mean that I'm not selection any columns from T2? because I'm selecting colx, coly, and colz from T2.

Comment: A simplified version of what you should be using:

    `SELECT col1, col2, col3, colx, coly, colz
    FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.col1=T2.coly and T2.Colz=1` Is this not giving the desired result? What is the error message/output you are getting?

Comment: @Chris if you want to return only columns from T1 why do you join? A left join will return all the rows of T1 so you could just `select col1, col2, col3 from T1`

Comment: @Chris No, you're not selecting anything from T2. You're making a temporary table of the specified columns from T2 and joining on that, but nothing from T2 will make it into your results. Your join does absolutely nothing.

Comment: @forpas a join will also return duplicated rows if eg multiple identical values of coly are returned; subtly different to a simple select from one table

Comment: @babno the join may not be a no-op. You can't say for sure without looking at the data

Comment: @CaiusJard correct, so I'm trying to understand the requirement. Does it make sense to return duplicate rows?

Comment: @forpas "I've got this query `SELECT DISTINCT ... FROM T1 LEFT JOIN ...`" -- 5 minutes hence ;)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are quite different.

Comment: @CaiusJard Nothing is selected into the results from t2, and it's a left join so it won't change anything in t1. It doesn't matter what the data is, it will never do anything.

Comment: @babno I disagree. Suppose T2 has two rows where `coly` is 1, and t1 has one row where `col1` is 1. `SELECT * FROM t1` produces 1 row, `SELECT t1.* FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON col1 = coly` produces 2 rows. The join did not "do nothing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be syntactically correct, your subquery needs an alias. Always alias table names and fully qualify them in the select, unless they're a single table subquery (in which case you can get away with not aliasing but doing so is advised)

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT t2.coly FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.colz = 1) sub1 ON t1.col1=sub1.coly
```

The recommendation to alias ensures your queries carry on working if new columns with the same names as existing columns are added to tables used in the query. Without aliases, columns that are unique right now may become ambiguous in future. Differences can arise in subqueries too because a subquery can access the outer columns. Obscure bugs can be caused by deleting a column a subquery uses, but adding a column of the same name to an outer table. The query still runs but the subquery starts pulling data from the wrong place

Comment: Just going to mention here since he said this was his answer. The join is not utilized at all and does absolutely nothing for the final result set. It's just wasted cpu time.

Answer (score 0):

You should write this query as:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
FROM T1;
```

I see no reason for the `JOIN`.  It can only duplicate rows in the result set, which is usually not desired.

This should work in any database.

If you had an inner join, I would recommend `exists`:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM T2
              WHERE t2.colz = 1 AND t1.col1 = t2.coly
             );
```

Comment: When you say "should" is there a definite (eg performance) reason for doing so [these days]? Also, might the EXISTS form give a different resultset to the JOIN form (join could produce more rows if a Cartesian product exists [and this might be desired])?

Comment: @CaiusJard . . . Incomplete thought.  I changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out:

```
SELECT T1.col1, T1.col2, T1.col3, T2.colx, T2.coly, T3.colz 
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 
   ON T1.col1=T2.coly and T2.Colz=1
```